# Javascript && operator versus nested if statements: what is faster?

Tags: javascript, performance, conditional-operator

Now, before you all jump on me and say "you're over concerned about performance," let it hereby stand that I ask this more out of curiosity than rather an overzealous nature.  That said...

I am curious if there is a performance difference between use of the && ("and") operator and nested if statements.  Also, is there an actual processing difference?  I.e., does && *always* process *both* statements, or will it stop @ the first one if the first one fails?  How would that be different than nested if statements?

Examples to be clear:

A) && ("and") operator

```
if(a == b && c == d) { ...perform some code fashizzle... }
```

versus B) nested if statements

```
if(a == b) {
    if(c == d) { ...perform some code fashizzle... }
}
```

Comment: Plus one for proper grammar and spelling.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The performance difference is negligible. The `&&` operator won't check the right hand expression when the left hand expression evaluates `false`. However, the `&` operator will check *both* regardless, maybe your confusion is caused by this fact.

In this particular example, I'd just choose the one using `&&`, since that's better readable.

Comment: Wasn't aware of forced & operator.  That's interesting!

Comment: Note that `&` is the /bitwise/ and operator. Thinking of it as a 'forced' version of `&&` isn't quite correct. Example: `1 && 2` is 2 while `1 & 2` is 0.

Answer (score 15):

If you're concerned about performance, then make sure that `a==b` is more likely to fail than `c==d`. That way the `if` statement will fail early.

Comment: Could someone shed some light on why I got a down vote on my answer?

Comment: I don't know -- your suggestion seems fine to me so I've upvoted you.

Comment: My guess is the -1 was because it doesn't *reeaally* address the question, which was a curiosity about a particular point of Javascript, rather than general optimization.

Comment: @Warren - Thanks. :) @Matchu - Well, it was already addressed by so many others in the thread. I just wanted to give him a hint on what to think about when it comes to IF statement design and performance. But I appreciate your comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Like nested `if`s, `&&` is lazy.
The expression `a && b` will only evaluate `b` if  `a` is truthful.

Therefore, the two cases should be completely identical, in both functionality and performance.

Comment: You probably meant "will only evaluate b if a is truthful".

Answer (score 3):

A peformance test might help clear things up: http://jsperf.com/simey-if-vs-if

Seems the performance difference is incredibly negligable between the two; However as @Gert mentioned, failing early really improves things.

Comment: To further this test case, I created a JSPerf (https://jsperf.com/operator-if-vs-nested-if) where the 2nd check is a slower performing one and the first is just a boolean. This gives a good comparison between the parser ignoring the 2nd check with the `&&` operator and nesting the checks.

In my test, using inline && is actually slightly faster than nested ifs (but only about ~0.1%)

Comment: oh nice, Mark, your test shows much clearer the benefit of failing early!